# How do I run the code in a loop until a click has been performed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to book a vaccine in my country. This code applies the filters and then clicks a slot if vaccines are available.

The first 3 lines select the filters and the last line clicks on an available slot.

```js
document.querySelector('.pin-search-btn.district-search.md.button.button-solid.ion-activatable.ion-focusable.hydrated').click()
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#c1').click()
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#c5').click()
  document.querySelectorAll('.vaccine-box').forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML !== ' Booked ' && item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML !== ' NA ') {
      item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
    }
  })
}, 2000);
```

```html
<-- html needed -->
```

I want to run this code in a loop over a 2 second time interval until the final click has been performed. `item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()`

P.S : I'm running this in Developer Tools on Chrome, I don't know if that info is relevant here or not.

Comment: It might help to post the HTML as well so we can better assist you.  Please explain a bit more than "execute click" - what are you really attempting to do?

Comment: I would also suggest you NOT leave out semi-colons as it will someday manifest a hard to find bug (paste your code here: https://jshint.com/

Comment: What do repeated clicks on the same element give you/do for you for example?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The page has a bug where it does not load on the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, I would suggest keeping a boolean `hasClickedSlot = false`, which you update once a slot has been clicked. Before calling `setTimeout` for 2 more seconds, ensure that `!hasClickedSlot` still holds.

That could look something like:

```js
let hasClickedSlot = false;

function clickButton() {
  document.querySelector('.pin-search-btn.district-search.md.button.button-solid.ion-activatable.ion-focusable.hydrated').click();
  
  // after 1 second, click on the C1 button
  setTimeout(clickC1, 1000);
}

function clickC1() {
  document.querySelector('#c1').click();
  
  // after 2 seconds, try to click on a slot
  setTimeout(tryClickSlot, 2000);
}


function tryClickSlot() {
  document.querySelector('#c5').click();
  document.querySelectorAll('.vaccine-box').forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML !== ' Booked ' && item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML !== ' NA ') {
      item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
      hasClickedSlot = true;
    }
  });

  // if no slot was clicked yet, do it again
  if (!hasClickedSlot) {
    clickButton();
  }
}

// start the process
clickButton();
```

<s>The disadvantage of this code specifically is that a stack of calls is built, as the functions do not return but rather keep stacking.</s>

Edit: Since the functions return after calling `setTimeout` no stack call is built (as it would during recursion, for instance).

Comment: This works perfectly sir ! Thank you very much. Though I do not understand what the implications of the function calls stacking up might be. Can I have it return something and never use the returned value ?

Comment: Never mind that remark. I just tested for a bit and the function returns after setting the timeout. This should work for you. Really annoying that you need such an approach in order to get a vaccine! The best of luck!